# Magento 2.4.3-p1 Hacked: Add to cart shows on URL javax.faces.resource.../WEB-INF/web.xml.jsf

Tags: nginx, magento, redis, magento2

Today my Magento 2.4.3-p1 site suddenly stop working as expected. Admin buttons doesn't work and in the product detail page all the add to cart buttons are disabled and on new product widget produdcts and other areas where I can add product to cart the url shows something like  "javax.faces.resource.../WEB-INF/web.xml.jsf" on URL.

Does anybody has any clue on this?.

Thanks

Comment: Things get worst with the passing of time... all add to cart and checkout buttons are disabled.... I think this is a xss atack and not documented yet by Magento.

Comment: Ok... after ran a check with Chkrootkit I've found this:

Checking `chkutmp'...                                        The tty of the following user process(es) were not found
 in /var/run/utmp !
! RUID          PID TTY    CMD
! =/etc/elasticsearch       0 e=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.distribution.flavor=default -Des.distribution.type=deb -Des.bundled_jdk=true -cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid --quiet
chkutmp: nothing deleted
Checking `OSX_RSPLUG'...                                    not tested

Comment: I had to restore the entire server from an old backup... everything, the whole server. I think the issue was related to the ElasticSuite Smile extension... Specifically with the elasticsearch plugins it requires.. analysis-phonetic and analysis-icu .